# php / js ui maintaince

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, twig

I'm searching for a ui library that would let me do server render with php standard stack (no v8 extension) and later let me maintain the view on client with js. I'm thinking about template engines available on both worlds like twig or handlebars. Kinda feel bad about stepping back from js wonderland and tooling. Maybe creating in browser a pipeline with twig rendered through react is an option? How would I link then server rendered stuff with client?

I'm searching for a declarative way of doing my UI, then client templating when data is pulled from server or user takes action and well, would love to write my component only once (that's way template engines covering both php and js are my first shot). However, php server render is strict requirement for the project and php there is just regular shared hosting defaults.

Any thoughts on that, have anyone went that route? Hopefully its not dead one.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

As the author of an open-source project [Agile UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui), I invite you to check it out.

Agile UI is a component PHP framework that makes it easy for browser and server-side to interact. The UI is built by creating objects then binding them to the parent object, similarly to how it's done in Desktop / Mobile applications.

Each component can have a custom HTML but comes with a built-in template. Here is a sample code for a fully-funcitonal web application:

```
$app = new \atk4\ui\App('My App');
$app->initLayout(new \atk4\ui\Layout\Admin());

$db = \atk4\data\Persistence::connect($DSN);

class User extends \atk4\data\Model {
    public $table = 'user';
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('email', ['required'=>true]);
        $this->addField('password', ['type'=>'password']);
    }
}

$app->layout->add(new \atk4\ui\CRUD())
  ->setModel(new User($db));
```

Result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The keyword you should google for is SSR (server side rendering), you will soon find serveral tutorials on different frameworks like [react ssr](https://medium.com/@liheyse/react-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-express-and-css-modules-722ef0cc8fa0) or [vue.js ssr](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/).